# Package pgfError in UML USE Case Diagram Association

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-uml

I am making an UML diagram using `tikz-uml` style. But it throws the following error, while developing the association relationship. I have used `\umlactor` and `\umlusecase` options to generate the actors and use cases. But found difficulty to generate the association relationship between the actors and use cases. I don't know how to resolve it, as because i am new to tikz. Any help is appreciated. The diagram will run smoothly, provided that the `\umlassoc` tags are commented. What is this error about `Package pgf Error: No shape named usecase-3 is known. \umlassoc{E}{usecase-3}`?

The MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{umlsystem}[x=0,y=2.5]{SYSTEM} 
\umlusecase[x=0,y=-4]{usecase-3} 
\umlusecase[x=0,y=-2]{use case2}
\end{umlsystem}  

\umlactor[x=-3, y=-.1, anchor=east]{D}  
\umlactor[x=-2, y=-3, anchor=north]{S}  
\umlactor[x=2, y=-3, anchor=north]{E} 
\umlactor[x=-2, y=3]{T}
\umlactor[x=2, y=3]{I}

\umlassoc{E}{usecase-3} 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{High Level.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of the `tikz-uml` package, you have to use the automatic number given by the package (see [here](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/html/web-tikz-uml-userguide.html#QQ2-5-107)):

> The text argument is the label of the use case. The node representing
>   the use case has a default name, based on a global counter, that is
>   like usecase-17. For pratical reasons, you can rename it thanks to the
>   name option.

For this reason, you should name your use cases by using the `name` argument for it or use `usecase-1` in your case:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{umlsystem}[x=0,y=2.5]{SYSTEM} 
\umlusecase[x=0,y=-4,name=usecase3]{usecase-3} 
\umlusecase[x=0,y=-2]{use case2}
\end{umlsystem} 

\umlactor[x=-3, y=-.1, anchor=east]{D}  
\umlactor[x=-2, y=-3, anchor=north]{S}  
\umlactor[x=2, y=-3, anchor=north]{E} 
\umlactor[x=-2, y=3]{T}
\umlactor[x=2, y=3]{I}

\umlassoc{E}{usecase3}
% or \umlassoc{E}{usecase-1}, if you remove the name argument from the usecase

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{High Level.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```